# Predecessor query where the insertion order is known

Tags: data-structures, runtime-analysis

Assume I want to insert elements $1$ to $n$ into a data structure exactly once, and perform predecessor queries while inserting these elements (so `insert(x)` and `pred(x)` always come in pairs). The predecessor of $x$ is the largest number in the data structure that is smaller than $x$.

The data structure is created by preprocessing the list of insertions.

When I start to insert elements, an adversary decides to delete some of the elements I have inserted, by adding any number of deletion operations between my insertions.

A query input to the data structure is a sequence of insertions and deletions, which is the insertion sequence with deletions inserted. 
The output of the query is the result of the $n$ predecessor queries executed when the elements are inserted.

Can one design a data structure so the query takes $O(n)$?

Here is an example.

```
Insertions = [1,3,5,4,2]
DS = makeDataStructure(Insertions)//Runs in polynomial time
//add some deletions into insertions
Operations = [1,3,-3,5,-1,4,-5,-4,2,-2]
DS.query(Operations)//this runs in O(n) time
```

Assume -i = delete i. And pred(x) = 0 if there is nothing before it.
result would be:

```
[pred(1)=0, pred(3)=1, pred(5)=1, pred(4)=0, pred(2)=0]
```

for example, the 3rd in the result is `pred(5)=1` instead of 3 because 3 is deleted when 5 is inserted.

Comment: Please check my edits to make sure that they reflect your original meaning. Can you illustrate the problem by providing an example of what you're talking about? I mean, with input and output. Thanks!

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, you do the following sequence $n$ times: insert some element $x$ + delete an arbitrary number of elements + do a query for the predecessor of $x$. You want to bound the total time taken by every sequence to be $O(n)$, for a total running time of $O(n^2)$?

Comment: actually I want to bound each operation by amortized time O(1), and the entire sequence of operation O(n). I wil update my problem with an example.

Comment: Are the elements to be inserted sorted to begin with, or unsorted but have keys [1,n]?

Comment: the element to be inserted are natural numbers. The insertion order might be different from its natural order. See the example.

Comment: How large is your universe? If you have a small universe van Emde Boas trees, or y-fast trees might be an option.